# Tkinter destroying a window (root) gives error

Tags: python, tkinter

Whenever I call root.destroy(), I get an error irrelevant to the code. I have no clue why it's erroring when I try to close the window.

New, updated code including all functions:

```py
import pyautogui
import database
import customtkinter
import tkinter
import settings
import os
import threading
import time

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

global curselect
curselect = ()

font1=("Arial",15,"bold")
font2=("Arial",12,"bold")
font3=("Arial",10,"italic")

for f in os.listdir("reagents"):
    text = f.replace('.png','')
    if not f in settings.reagents:
        settings.possible[text] = f


def ExitWindow(windowtoexit):
    windowtoexit.destroy()

def loginUI():
    loginRoot = customtkinter.CTk()
    loginRoot.geometry("650x175")
    loginRoot.title("Bazaar Bot - Login")
    loginRoot.resizable(False, False)

    def Login():
        username = userentry.get()
        password = passentry.get()
        res = database.login(username, password)
        if res == "Success!":
            ExitWindow(loginRoot)
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(res, "Successfully logged in.")
            mainUI()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", res)
    def gotoRegister():
        loginRoot.destroy()
        registerUI()

    userlabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=loginRoot, text="Username:", font=font1)
    userlabel.place(x=15, y=10)
    passlabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=loginRoot, text="Password:", font=font1)
    passlabel.place(x=15, y=50)

    userentry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=loginRoot, font=font2, width=535)
    userentry.place(x=100, y=10)
    passentry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=loginRoot, font=font2, width=535, show="•")
    passentry.place(x=100, y=50)

    lostpassword = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=loginRoot, text="Lost password?", font=font2, width=620, height=20, fg_color="transparent")
    lostpassword.pack()
    lostpassword.place(x=15, y=85)

    register = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=loginRoot, text="Want to register with serial key?", font=font2, width=620, height=20, fg_color="transparent", command=gotoRegister)
    register.pack()
    register.place(x=15, y=110)

    login = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=loginRoot, text="Login", font=font1, width=620, command=Login)
    login.pack()
    login.place(x=15, y=140)

    loginRoot.mainloop()

invalid = [' ', ',', '+', '-', '=', '\'', '/', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}']

def registerUI():
    def Register():
        if len(userentry.get()) <= 4:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Username must be at least 5 characters.")
            return
        if len(passentry1.get()) <= 4:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password must be at least 5 characters.")
            return
        if passentry1.get() != passentry2.get():
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Passwords are not the same.")
            return
        if len(emailentry1.get()) <= 3:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please input a valid email address.")
            return
        if emailentry1.get() != emailentry2.get():
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Emails are not the same.")
            return
        for i in invalid:
            if i in userentry.get():
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Username cannot contain '" + i + "'")
                return
        for i in invalid:
            if i in emailentry1.get():
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Email cannot contain '" + i + "'")
                return

        key = licenseentry.get()
        username = userentry.get()
        password = passentry1.get()
        email = emailentry1.get()

        if database.checkuserexists(username):
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Username already in use.")
        if database.checkemailexists(email):
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Email already in use.")
        status = database.checklicensekey(key, username, password, email)
        if status == "Success! Please log in.":
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success!", status)
            ExitWindow(registerRoot)
            loginUI()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", status)
        #print() #key isn't used already, key is linked to owner

    registerRoot = customtkinter.CTk()
    registerRoot.geometry("650x375")
    registerRoot.title("Bazaar Bot - Registration")
    registerRoot.resizable(False, False)

    userlabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="Username:", font=font1)
    userlabel.place(x=15, y=10)
    userentry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=registerRoot, font=font2, width=480)
    userentry.place(x=160, y=10)

    passinfo = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="(Make sure you remember your password! You will need it to log in again.)", font=font3, text_color='#808080')
    passinfo.place(x=160, y=60)
    passlabel1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="Password:", font=font1)
    passlabel1.place(x=15, y=80)
    passentry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=registerRoot, font=font2, width=480, show="•")
    passentry1.place(x=160, y=80)
    passlabel2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="Confirm Password:", font=font1)
    passlabel2.place(x=15, y=120)
    passentry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=registerRoot, font=font2, width=480, show="•")
    passentry2.place(x=160, y=120)

    emailinfo = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="(Make sure you put in a valid email address! You will need to verify it later.)", font=font3, text_color='#808080')
    emailinfo.place(x=160, y=170)
    emaillabel1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="Email:", font=font1)
    emaillabel1.place(x=15, y=190)
    emailentry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=registerRoot, font=font2, width=480)
    emailentry1.place(x=160, y=190)
    emaillabel2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="Confirm Email:", font=font1)
    emaillabel2.place(x=15, y=230)
    emailentry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=registerRoot, font=font2, width=480)
    emailentry2.place(x=160, y=230)

    licenseinfo = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="(Your license key was sent to you via email when you purchased bazaarbot.)", font=font3, text_color='#808080')
    licenseinfo.place(x=160, y=270)
    licenselabel1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=registerRoot, text="License Key:", font=font1)
    licenselabel1.place(x=15, y=290)
    licenseentry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=registerRoot, font=font2, width=480, show="•")
    licenseentry.place(x=160, y=290)

    register = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=registerRoot, text="Register", font=font1, width=620, command=Register)
    register.pack()
    register.place(x=15, y=340)

    registerRoot.mainloop()


def mainUI():
    def onClosing():
        if tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?"):
            mainRoot.destroy()
            #exit()
    def changeCoords():
        while True:
            pos = pyautogui.position()
            xPos.configure(text="X: " + str(pos[0]))
            yPos.configure(text="Y: " + str(pos[1]))
            time.sleep(.025)

    def possibleClicked(stuff):
        global curselect
        if possibleListbox.curselection():
            curselect = possibleListbox.curselection()
        selectedItem = possibleListbox.get(curselect)
        possibleListbox.delete(curselect)
        if selectedItem != '':
            selectedListbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
    def selectedClicked(stuff):
        global curselect
        if selectedListbox.curselection():
            curselect = selectedListbox.curselection()
        selectedItem = selectedListbox.get(curselect)
        selectedListbox.delete(curselect)
        if selectedItem != '':
            possibleListbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)

    mainRoot = customtkinter.CTk()
    mainRoot.geometry("650x400")
    mainRoot.title("Bazaar Bot")
    mainRoot.resizable(False, False)

    mainRoot.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", onClosing)

    xPos = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="X: 0", font=font2)
    xPos.place(x=15, y=120)
    yPos = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="Y: 0", font=font2)
    yPos.place(x=15, y=140)

    threading.Thread(target=changeCoords).start()

    reagentposition = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="Reagent Position:", font=font1)
    reagentposition.place(x=15, y=240)
    xLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="X:", font=font1)
    xLabel.place(x=15, y=270)
    xEntry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=mainRoot, font=font2, width=100)
    xEntry.place(x=35, y=270)
    yLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="Y:", font=font1)
    yLabel.place(x=15, y=300)
    yEntry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=mainRoot, font=font2, width=100)
    yEntry.place(x=35, y=300)

    start = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=mainRoot, text="Start", font=font1, width=120, height=40)
    start.place(x=15, y=345)
    save = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=mainRoot, text="Save", font=font1, width=120, height=40)
    save.place(x=150, y=345)

    possible = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="Possible Reagents", font=font2, width=110)
    possible.place(x=400, y=8)
    possibleListbox = tkinter.Listbox(mainRoot, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, activestyle=tkinter.NONE, width=15, height=10)
    possibleListbox.place(x=400,y=30)
    possibleScrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(mainRoot)
    possibleScrollbar.place(x=493, y=30, height=164)
    possibleListbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", possibleClicked)
    possibleListbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", possibleClicked)
    possibleListbox.config(yscrollcommand=possibleScrollbar.set)
    possibleScrollbar.config(command=possibleListbox.yview)

    selected = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="Selected Reagents", font=font2, width=110)
    selected.place(x=530, y=8)
    selectedListbox = tkinter.Listbox(mainRoot, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, activestyle=tkinter.NONE, width=15, height=10)
    selectedListbox.place(x=530, y=30)
    selectedScrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(mainRoot)
    selectedScrollbar.place(x=623, y=30, height=164)
    selectedListbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", selectedClicked)
    selectedListbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", selectedClicked)
    selectedListbox.config(yscrollcommand=selectedScrollbar.set)
    selectedScrollbar.config(command=selectedListbox.yview)

    log = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=mainRoot, text="Log", font=font2, width=110)
    log.place(x=360, y=200)
    logListbox = tkinter.Listbox(mainRoot, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, exportselection=False, width=37, height=10)
    logListbox.place(x=400, y=222)
    logScrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(mainRoot)
    logScrollbar.place(x=623, y=222, height=164)
    logListbox.config(yscrollcommand=logScrollbar.set)
    logScrollbar.config(command=logListbox.yview)

    possibleListbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    selectedListbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)

    for i in settings.possible:
        possibleListbox.insert(tkinter.END, i)
    for i in settings.reagents:
        selectedListbox.insert(tkinter.END, i.replace('.png',''))

    mainRoot.mainloop()

#registerUI()
#mainUI()
loginUI()
```

Here is pretty much all of the code, the error happens when I call registerUI(). Without this line, the loginUI window closes fine by itself.

error:
invalid command name "1693004801088check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"1693004801088check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1693027104576update"
while executing
"1693027104576update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1693028003328_click_animation"
while executing
"1693028003328_click_animation"
("after" script)

Process finished with exit code 0

[gif](https://gyazo.com/f8ad2203da48d1384981b1b575dcc880)

Comment: You destroy `root` and then you call method `mainloop()` on it. This looks wrong. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of errors or code. Instead, include the error message in your question as text.

Comment: included more code, check it now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are destroying root before calling the `mainloop()`

If you do it like this for example it works because the root is only destroyed after the button is clicked and that is only possible when the window is already drawn

```py
import customtkinter


def ExitWindow():
    print("exit")
    root.destroy()  # <---- error cause


root = customtkinter.CTk()  # custom tkinter, similar to tkinter
root.geometry("650x375")
root.title("Bazaar Bot - Registration")
root.resizable(False, False)

# some extra code here, irrelevant.

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, command=ExitWindow)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry, the code I posted wasn't clear as it was just a sample of all my code. Check the original post, I've edited it.

Comment: @Gummi i can't really debug it since most of the stuff that is called is not included in your given code so no idea what the issue is, please provide your full code

Comment: @Gummi please just provide the full code, `mainUi` and `ExitWindow` are missing now for example. I can't run your code so i cant debug it as well. Please test your own code before you submit it to make sure its runnable

Comment: I've now added in ALL the code.

Answer (score 0):

call mainloop without root

```
from tkinter import mainloop
# not to use registerRoot.mainloop()
mainloop()
```

Comment: this doesn't work as I'm using multiple roots for different windows, right?